# Assign /112 IPv6 range to OpenVZ VPS

Tags: ipv6, openvz

I have a /48 IPv6 and would like to chop these up into /112's that I can assign to my VPSes.
I know how to assign them manually, e.g.

```
vzctl set 1 --ipadd ipv6IP --save
```

But how could I assign, for example, a full /112 at once?

Comment: You want to assign "a full /112 at once" to what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [veth](http://wiki.openvz.org/Veth). In VE:

```
/sbin/ip -6 addr add IPv6_ADDR/112 dev eth0
```

Comment: In the virtual machine??

Comment: Yes, in the virtual machine.

Comment: I don't want to be able to assign them in the VE i want to assign them from the host node. E.G. if i sold some vpses i don't want just anyone to take their own amount of ipv6

Answer (score 0):

That takes several steps:

1. In the CT0 (the "host"), add a veth to the VE (the "VM"):

   ```
   vzctl set <CTID> --netif_add eth0
   ```
2. In the CT0, enable IPv6 forwarding (`net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` will do that, temporarily. Consult the docs of your OS for how to make that permanent.)
3. In the CT0, add a route for the /112 to the VE's virtual interface. For example, assuming your VE has a CTID 1:

   ```
   ip -6 route add IP6_NET/112 dev veth1.0
   ```
4. This concludes the setup in the CF0.
5. Now, finally, *in your VE* add addresses you want to use (from the subnet) to the VE's eth0:

   ```
   ip -6 addr add IP6_IP dev eth0
   ```